# Static Google Map with Markers

Tags: asp.net

I have used static google map and need to create a marker label with **custom name**. Please provide me the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You could use the StyledMarker.js library. See http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmarker/docs/examples.html